# Magento 2 - Serve cached content from Varnish while fetching a new object from the backend to deliver it on the next request

Tags: full-page-cache, varnish, magento2.4.5

When I change any objects in the Magento backend, a PURGE request is sent to Varnish which results in a slow response time once a customer requests the changed product. The site is then loaded into cache, so that the following customers will have a faster page loading.
So far so good.

I want to prevent that this "unlucky" customer is experiencing the slow reponse.
I want that the first request after purging/invalidating the cache still serves the old value, while fetching the new value from the backend, putting it into the Varnish cache and delivering it upon the next request as a HIT on the cache.

I already discovered the "soft purge" function, but did not manage to make it work. It either did not work or resulted in the product not being updated at all.

The following Varnish config was generated using the Magento backend. Except for the hostnames, everything is on default.

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 6
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 6.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "web-host01.example.com;
    .port = "80";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "web-host01.example.com";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.restarts > 0) {
        set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }

    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass customer, shopping cart, checkout
    if (req.url ~ "/customer" || req.url ~ "/checkout") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(health_check.php)$") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    # Bypass authenticated GraphQL requests without a X-Magento-Cache-Id
    if (req.url ~ "/graphql" && !req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id && req.http.Authorization ~ "^Bearer") {
        return (pass);
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if ((req.url !~ "/graphql" || !req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) && req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
    

    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        call process_graphql_headers;
    }
}

sub process_graphql_headers {
    if (req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id);

        # When the frontend stops sending the auth token, make sure users stop getting results cached for logged-in users
        if (req.http.Authorization ~ "^Bearer") {
            hash_data("Authorized");
        }
    }

    if (req.http.Store) {
        hash_data(req.http.Store);
    }

    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s that are not marked as private
    if (beresp.status != 200 &&
            beresp.status != 404 &&
            beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
   }

   # If the cache key in the Magento response doesn't match the one that was sent in the request, don't cache under the request's key
   if (bereq.url ~ "/graphql" && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id && bereq.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id != beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Id) {
      set beresp.ttl = 0s;
      set beresp.uncacheable = true;
   }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
        set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    if (!resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (restart);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

varnishlog after purging

```
*   << BeReq    >> 65548     
-   Begin          bereq 65547 fetch
-   VCL_use        boot
-   Timestamp      Start: 1666813603.131250 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /example-req-url
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
-   BereqHeader    Host: staging.example.com
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
-   BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   BereqHeader    Referer: https://staging.example.com/path/to/something
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
-   BereqHeader    Cookie: COOKIES
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.10.10
-   BereqHeader    Via: 1.1 varnish-host01 (Varnish/7.2)
-   BereqHeader    grace: none
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 65548
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1666813603.131283 0.000032 0.000032
-   Timestamp      Connected: 1666813603.131767 0.000517 0.000484
-   BackendOpen    27 web-host01 172.19.25.32 80 172.19.25.34 36108 connect
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1666813603.131833 0.000583 0.000065
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1666813604.043211 0.911961 0.911378
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   200
-   BerespReason   OK
-   BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2022 19:46:43 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
-   BerespHeader   Expires: Thu, 27 Oct 2022 19:46:43 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
-   BerespHeader   Pragma: cache
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3drps5kqelveq4nl3cf41pdggd; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: form_key=3UR6dQy6ODHqy3w3; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3drps5kqelveq4nl3cf41pdggd; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3drps5kqelveq4nl3cf41pdggd; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: X-Magento-Vary=2627569dcdbeca193d32905c799896fce3eeb169; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:44 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespHeader   X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,cms_b_custom_navigation_links,cms_b_header_top_message,cms_b_header_top_quicklink,cms_b_page_bottom_steps,cms_b_page_bottom_faq_outer,cms_b_page_bottom_faq,cms_b_page_bottom_faq_background,cms_b_prefooter_block,cms_b_footer_bo
-   BerespHeader   Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: font-src fonts.gstatic.com https://widgets.trustedshops.com https://integrations.etrusted.com data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.c
-   BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   BerespHeader   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
-   BerespHeader   Content-Length: 19070
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   TTL            RFC 86400 10 0 1666813604 1666813604 1666813603 1666900003 86400 cacheable
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   TTL            VCL 86400 259200 0 1666813604 cacheable
-   BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3drps5kqelveq4nl3cf41pdggd; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: form_key=3UR6dQy6ODHqy3w3; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3drps5kqelveq4nl3cf41pdggd; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3drps5kqelveq4nl3cf41pdggd; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:43 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=staging.example.com; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: X-Magento-Vary=2627569dcdbeca193d32905c799896fce3eeb169; expires=Wed, 26-Oct-2022 20:46:44 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1666813604.043276 0.912026 0.000065
-   Filters         gunzip esi_gzip
-   BerespUnset    Content-Encoding: gzip
-   BerespUnset    Content-Length: 19070
-   BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
-   Storage        malloc s0
-   Fetch_Body     3 length -
-   Gzip           G F E 87119 19971 80 159688 159698
-   Gzip           U F - 19070 87119 80 80 152490
-   BackendClose   27 web-host01 recycle
-   Timestamp      BerespBody: 1666813604.050210 0.918960 0.006933
-   Length         19971
-   BereqAcct      1377 0 1377 6858 19070 25928
-   End            

*   << Request  >> 65547     
-   Begin          req 65546 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1666813603.130872 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1666813603.130872 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       192.168.10.10 3330 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /example-req-url
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      Host: staging.example.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   ReqHeader      Referer: https://staging.example.com/path/to/something
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: __delivery_area_postcode=00000; __delivery_area_storeId=3; store=beelitz; form_key=3UR6dQy6ODHqy3w3; mage-messages=; mage-cache-storage={}; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation={}; recently_viewed_product={}; recently_viewed_product_previous={
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.10.10
-   ReqHeader      Via: 1.1 varnish-host01 (Varnish/7.2)
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /example-req-url
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   ExpBan         3 banned lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 65548 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1666813604.050238 0.919365 0.919365
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 26 Oct 2022 19:46:43 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
-   RespHeader     Expires: Thu, 27 Oct 2022 19:46:43 GMT
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
-   RespHeader     Pragma: cache
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,cms_b_custom_navigation_links,cms_b_header_top_message,cms_b_header_top_quicklink,cms_b_page_bottom_steps,cms_b_page_bottom_faq_outer,cms_b_page_bottom_faq,cms_b_page_bottom_faq_background,cms_b_prefooter_block,cms_b_footer_bo
-   RespHeader     Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: font-src fonts.gstatic.com https://widgets.trustedshops.com https://integrations.etrusted.com data: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.c
-   RespHeader     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   RespHeader     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   RespHeader     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 65547
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-host01 (Varnish/7.2)
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Cache-Debug: HIT
-   RespHeader     Grace: none
-   RespUnset      Pragma: cache
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespUnset      Expires: Thu, 27 Oct 2022 19:46:43 GMT
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespUnset      Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespUnset      X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,cms_b_custom_navigation_links,cms_b_header_top_message,cms_b_header_top_quicklink,cms_b_page_bottom_steps,cms_b_page_bottom_faq_outer,cms_b_page_bottom_faq,cms_b_page_bottom_faq_background,cms_b_prefooter_block,cms_b_footer_bo
-   RespUnset      Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 65547
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish-host01 (Varnish/7.2)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1666813604.050321 0.919449 0.000083
-   Filters         esi
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Link           req 65549 esi 1
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1666813604.050855 0.919982 0.000533
-   ReqAcct        1328 0 1328 5467 23108 28575
-   End            

*   << Session  >> 65546     
-   Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
-   SessOpen       192.168.10.10 3330 a0 172.19.25.34 80 1666813603.129864 24
-   Link           req 65547 rxreq
-   SessClose      TX_EOF 0.921
-   End
```

I'm currently running Varnish 7.2 in front of Magento 2.4.5. I also tested Varnish 6. So that's not an issue.